# Function-point measure in quality control or assurance

Tags: metrics, software-quality, function-points

I am looking for 3 examples of how I can use function-point measure in quality control or assurance over some other simpler measures i.e. 3 examples where function-points are preferable over some other simpler methods in quality control/assurance.

Comment: Could you give an example of how you think function points can be used to control quality? I don't think that's what they're for. Alexander Serebrenik's answer sums it up quite well, I think.

Answer (score 0):

Function points are used to estimate the effort required to build an application. An alternative would be, e.g., COCOMO which is based on the number of lines of code. FP-based approaches are often considered to be preferrable to COCOMO at early stages of the project development when no clear estimate of the number of lines of code to be developed can yet be given.

Another advantage of the FP-based effort estimation is provided by availability of effort tables (e.g., in Capers Jones' books) for different kinds of applications and different kinds of activities involved in a software project. Hence, by using FPs project manager can obtain a more refined insight in the effort required.